# Unread notifications not showing in API response

Tags: support, inbox, api-v2.3

I have been trying to fetch all unread notifications  from the Stack Exchange API. However, I always get a blank `items` data in the response.

**API Endpoint:**

```
/2.3/me/notifications/unread?page=1&pagesize=10&site=stackoverflow
```

**JSON received:**

```
{
  "items": [],
  "has_more": false,
  "quota_max": 10000,
  "quota_remaining": 9975
}
```

I do have an unread notification as in the below screenshot:

[image]

I experience the same behavior when I deliberately make a notification unread.

I am referring to [`this API doc`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-unread-notifications#page=1&pagesize=10&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not the notifications you're looking for ... It's confusing, but you need the inbox methods instead: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/inbox-unread#filter=default&run=true

You can get an idea about what notifications (in the API) *are* by looking at the `notification_type` on [this page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/notification).